# Why the temporary variable needs in changing array elements and why it needs to be unset at the end?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, reference, unset

Consider below code snippet which changes(convert the values to uppercase) the values of the array directly by passing them by reference.

```
<?php
  $colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');

  foreach ($colors as &$color) {
    $color = strtoupper($color);
  }
  unset($color); /* ensure that following writes to
  $color will not modify the last array element */

  print_r($colors);

?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => RED
    [1] => BLUE
    [2] => GREEN
    [3] => YELLOW
)
```

**I've not understood the code above at all.** I've few doubts regarding the above code as follows :

1. I didn't understand this statement at all `$color = strtoupper($color);` from inside a `foreach` loop. Why the temporary variable `$color` is used and in the function `strtoupper()` why the reference `&$color` is not passed and only `$color` is passed?
2. Why the variable `$color` has been unset? What did that contain inside before unsetting?
3. What's the meaning of the comment **"ensure that following writes to
   $color will not modify the last array element"** as the last element from array i.e. **yellow** is also getting modified?

**In short please explain me what's happening out there in the code from `foreach` loop in a step-by step manner.**

Please someone answer my doubts.

**Note : The above code example has been taken from the PHP Manual's Array chapter.**

Comment: remove/comment the `unset` call, add a write to the `$color` variable at the end (before the `print_r` call of course) and you'll get it pretty soon.

Comment: the point is to comment/remove the unset() here to see the actual magic happening. Answer coming up.

Comment: As a side note, in order to achieve that you can use array_map : $colors = array_map("strtoupper", $colors );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defensive programming at work here.

On each iteration of the `foreach()` loop, a reference to the current item value is created in the `$color` variable, allowing to write a new value to it. When the iteration is over though, the `$color` variable still contains a reference to the last array item's value, allowing a programmer reusing the `$color` variable for writing to update that item in the array, which is probably not the intended result. `unset()`ting the variable after the loop destroys the reference and avoids that risk.

Building on top of your example :

```
<?php
$colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');

foreach ($colors as &$color) {
  $color = strtoupper($color);
}
//unset($color); 
/* ensure that following writes to
$color will not modify the last array element */

print_r($colors);
$color='hello';
print_r($colors);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => RED
    [1] => BLUE
    [2] => GREEN
    [3] => YELLOW
)
Array
(
    [0] => RED
    [1] => BLUE
    [2] => GREEN
    [3] => hello
)
```

https://eval.in/897010